# Computing per-vertex (site) Voronoi cell areas directly from a Delaunay triangulation

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, voronoi, delaunay

I wish to compute the areas of Voronoi cells which relate to a Delaunay triangulation of a point set without explicitly converting the Delaunay triangulation to a Voronoi graph.
Since I only care about the areas of the Voronoi cells I wanted to avoid the cost of explicitly constructing the Voronoi data structure. Is this possible? Is there any relationship between the Delaunay triangulation/circles and the dual Voronoi cell areas?
Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 0):

Using [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org), a solution is provided here for the 3D case:

https://lists-sop.inria.fr/sympa/arc/cgal-discuss/2011-01/msg00117.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) once you know the vertices of the Voronoi cell in counter-clockwise order. This, however, is simple as the Delaunay triangulation is the [dual of the Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Relationship_with_the_Voronoi_diagram): A Voronoi vertex is dual to a Delaunay triangle, and the vertex is located at the point equidistant to the triangle's corners.

So if you are interested in the area of the Voronoi cell of a point p in a pointset then (i) consider all incident Delaunay triangles T in counter-clockwise order, (ii) compute the loci of the Voronoi nodes, and (iii) plug in into Shoelace formula.